# The critical values of $f(x)= x^3-6x^2+9$

Tags: calculus

Find the critical values of this function $$f(x)= x^3-6x^2+9$$

Thanks Siminore, You had the least confusing solution that would have brought me to the correct answer as shown in the book. What was confusing to me is when I got the $3x^2-12x$ I did not know whether to add 12x to both sides of $3x^2-12x=0$ or any clue of where to go from there being that I had an x attached to the 12 (12x). Now if I had $3x^2-12$ I could have set it equal to zero and solved, This I undersatand it was the second varible that through me off. But The answer to the my original problem is x=0 x=4. This how i got it.

$3x^2-12x$

$3x(x-4)=0$

$3x/3=0$

thus x=0

$x-4+4=0+4$

$x=4$

Comment: Do you know what a critical value is?

Comment: Kind of... Not directly sure

Comment: A critical value $y$ is the image $y = f(p)$ of a critical point $p$, that is a $p$ with $f'(p) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

A critical point of a function is where the function is neither increasing nor decreasing. In other words, it is where $f'(x) = 0$. (Recall, when $f'(x) >0$, the function $f(x)$ is increasing, and when $f'(x) < 0$, the function is decreasing).

[Note: when given a function defined over a closed interval $[a, b]$, you also need to check and compare the values of $f(a), f(b)$ with the values of $f(x)$ when $f'(x) = 0$ in order to determine whether either endpoint is a  maximum/minimum of the function, as well as checking points at which the derivative is undefined.]

Now, $$f(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 + 9 \implies f'(x) = 3x^2 - 12 x.$$

$$f'(x) = 0 \iff 3x^2 - 12 x = 0 \iff 3x(x - 4) = 0.$$

So the derivative is zero if and only if $x = 0$, or $x = 4$.

So the critical values in this case are given by $$(0, f(0)), (4, f(4)).$$

Answer (score 0):

Critical values are associated to critical points, so find critical points first: $f'(x)=3x^2-12x=0$. Find $x_1$ and $x_2$, then compute $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

So for you to know, Critical point is the point of a function where its derivative is 0.
That is, $f'(x) =0$

For this function above $f'(x)=3x^2 -12x$

EDIT: Calculation mistake.
At x=0 and x=4 the value of $f'(x) =0$

Now, Calculate $f(0)$ and $f(4)$ to get critical values.

Comment: That's not correct. $$3x^2 - 12x = 3x(x-4) = 0 \iff x = 0, \text{ or } x = 4$$

Comment: Thanks for the correction.Ill update it. :)